# What happens if a Master Page doesn't meet the Site Definitions

Tags: master-page, site-definition, customization

What happens when your master page doesn't meet the site definitions?

Will it still render correctly?

Currently my master has the blue 'i' icon and doesn't meet site definitions. But still looks okay.

Answer (score 1):

> SharePoint pages are, by default, associated with site definition
>   files. When a master page is customized in SharePoint Designer 2010,
>   it is no longer associated with the site definition. This can result
>   in additional administrative work following future updates or upgrades
>   to SharePoint, which is why you see this message. You can always reset
>   the master page to its site definition, if necessary.

Source:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-0A57B837-4C97-4AF9-A088-FEDF3DFD1DD5

Comment: So what is that additional work? (*I always click Yes but never understood what I was doing*)